# How can electron hopping occur in the tight binding model if the energy levels are localized to atomic orbitals on each atom?

Tags: tight-binding

In other words, what is the reason for electron hopping? Is not to related to overlap of orbitals between adjacent atoms ( say, in nearest neighbour hopping Tight binding models)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the overlaps of the site orbitals with that if the nearest neighbours. In fact here is the result of Hartree’s calculations of the same. 
[image]

What is plotted is the radial part of the wavefunction vs distance. The inner orbitals don’t have significant overlap. But the outer ones do and contribute more to the hopping.